# Is there a way that I can set the iOS music app to save my progress during playback?

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

I've noticed since updating to iOS 9 that if I pause music playback in the middle of a song, then return to the music app after a period of time, the song begins playing again from the beginning. Not where I left off. This can get annoying if you are listening to a longer file, like a mix or (I would imagine) an audiobook. Is there a way for me to change the setting so that my position within the song will be remembered?

Comment: this is still relevant. in iOS 11.4.1 when I paused on any song, and I have a full album loaded into Apple Music.  I close my app, then opened it back. I have "Not Playing". as I didn't add any albums before.  This is so frustrating.  Comparing to as Google Music works. The position is saved by default everytime and the whole playlists and all songs are there.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the media type to audiobook or podcast it will give you the option to remember playback position, but it will be moved to the iBooks or Podcast app instead of being able to be played in Music.